# databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

When executing the following code provide by [databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/applications/machine-learning/preprocess-data/scikit-learn.html), an serialization error appears.
The code is basically an hyperopt optimization of the XGboost in the databricks environment. This code is part of an end-to-end tutorial provided by databricks.

**Code:**

```
from hyperopt import fmin, tpe, hp, SparkTrials, Trials, STATUS_OK
from hyperopt.pyll import scope
from math import exp
import mlflow.xgboost
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
 
pyspark.InheritableThread  
#mlflow.set_experiment("/Shared/experiments/ichi")
search_space = {
  'max_depth': scope.int(hp.quniform('max_depth', 4, 100, 1)),
  'learning_rate': hp.loguniform('learning_rate', -3, 0),
  'reg_alpha': hp.loguniform('reg_alpha', -5, -1),
  'reg_lambda': hp.loguniform('reg_lambda', -6, -1),
  'min_child_weight': hp.loguniform('min_child_weight', -1, 3),
  'objective': 'binary:logistic',
  'seed': 123, # Set a seed for deterministic training
}
 
def train_model(params):
  # With MLflow autologging, hyperparameters and the trained model are automatically logged to MLflow.
  mlflow.xgboost.autolog()
  with mlflow.start_run(nested=True):
    train = xgb.DMatrix(data=X_train, label=y_train)
    validation = xgb.DMatrix(data=X_val, label=y_val)
    # Pass in the validation set so xgb can track an evaluation metric. XGBoost terminates training when the evaluation metric
    # is no longer improving.
    booster = xgb.train(params=params, dtrain=train, num_boost_round=1000,\
                        evals=[(validation, "validation")], early_stopping_rounds=50)
    validation_predictions = booster.predict(validation)
    auc_score = roc_auc_score(y_val, validation_predictions)
    mlflow.log_metric('auc', auc_score)
 
    signature = infer_signature(X_train, booster.predict(train))
    mlflow.xgboost.log_model(booster, "model", signature=signature)
    
    # Set the loss to -1*auc_score so fmin maximizes the auc_score
    return {'status': STATUS_OK, 'loss': -1*auc_score, 'booster': booster.attributes()}
 
# Greater parallelism will lead to speedups, but a less optimal hyperparameter sweep. 
# A reasonable value for parallelism is the square root of max_evals.
spark_trials = SparkTrials(parallelism=10)
 
# Run fmin within an MLflow run context so that each hyperparameter configuration is logged as a child run of a parent
# run called "xgboost_models" .
with mlflow.start_run(run_name='xgboost_models'):
  best_params = fmin(
    fn=train_model, 
    space=search_space, 
    algo=tpe.suggest, 
    max_evals=96,
    trials=spark_trials,
  )
```

**The error is:**

```
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py:980: FutureWarning: Deprecated in 3.1, Use pyspark.InheritableThread with the pinned thread mode enabled.
  warnings.warn(

  0%|          | 0/96 [00:00<?, ?trial/s, best loss=?]trial task 0 failed, exception is Caused by Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 165, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 469, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/exceptions.py", line 83, in __init__
    error_code = json.get("error_code", ErrorCode.Name(INTERNAL_ERROR))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
.
 None
```

This code is excuted in the databricks notebook. I tried different versions for mlflow, pyspark and hyperopt but without sucess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SparkTrials` automatically track its runs, and it clashes with the tracking you explicitly set in the `train_model` function. Just remove all of the `mlflow` calls from the `train_model` and you are good to go.